# Batch multiplication of layer outputs and scalar factors in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

The model architecture I'm working with has `k` parallel convolution layers. The individual outputs of these layers are combined linearly using a MLP layer predicting weights. The model takes batch images as input and outputs batch images (with a different channel count).

A simplified `forward()` function is as follows:

```py
# the batch input
#   input channels = 3
#   input dimensions = 32x32
# x.size() = [128, 3, 32, 32]
x

# self.mlp = Flatten -> Linear -> LeakyReLU
# conv_weights.size() = [128, 8]
#   batch size = 128
#   8 scalar values for each of the 8 convolution layers
conv_weights = self.mlp(x)

# run convolutions
# self.convs = ModuleList([Conv2d -> BatchNorm2d -> LeakyReLU])
conv_outputs = []
for conv in self.convs:
    # size = [128, 32, 32, 32]
    #   output channels = 32
    #   output dimensions = 32x32
    conv_outputs.append(conv(x))

result = ???
```

I'm having trouble trying to multiply the convolution outputs with the scalar factors due to the additional dimension for the batch size. Without the batch size, I could simply do a scalar multiplication of each convolution layer.

How do I multiply the output of each convolution layer with the MLP output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine linearly your `n=8` outputs, you can first stack `conv_outputs` on `dim=1`. This leaves you with a tensor of shape `(b,n,c_out,h,w)`:

```
>>> conv_outputs = torch.stack(conv_outputs, dim=1)
```

Then broadcast `conv_weights` to `(b,n,1,1,1)` and multiply to `conv_outputs`. What matters is that dimensions of size `b` and size `n` remain in first positions. The last three dimensions are expanded automatically on `conv_weights` to compute the resulting tensor `linear_comb`:

```
>>> linear_comb = conv_weights[:,:,None,None,None]*conv_outputs
```

Now linear_comb is shaped `(b,8,c_out,h,w)`, finish by reducing `dim=1`:

```
>>> result = linear_comb.sum(1)
```

Final shape is `(b,c_out,h,w)`.